# CoreData Sort by relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

My relation is shown on the picture below.

[image: CoreData relation]

I'd like to sort Events first by those that are in active promotion and then by start date. Promotion is active if current date is between start and end date. Unfortunately, because of CoreData, I'm not able to use transient properties for sorting. In my controller I'm not using a fetch controller.

Is there any way to achieve that?

**Update:**

I've following sort descriptors:

```
// First is incorrect
[NSSortDescriptor(key: "promotion.start", ascending: false), 
NSSortDescriptor(key: "start", ascending: true)]
```

Predicates (They're ok, though):

```
let promotionsPredicate =
    NSPredicate(format: "(%@ >= promotion.start && %@ <= promotion.end) && " +
                "(ANY promotion.cities.id == %@)", NSDate(), NSDate(), objectID)
let eventsPredicate =
    NSPredicate(format: "start >= %@ && venue.city.id == %@",
                                NSDate(), objectID)

let subpredicates = [eventsPredicate, promotionsPredicate]                    
let compoundPredicate NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subpredicates)
```

And this is the Request (I'm using CoreStore, but the idea should be clear):

```
class func pagedEventsForPredicateSortedByInPromoAndStartDate(predicate: NSPredicate,
                                                              descriptors: [NSSortDescriptor],
                                                              fetchOffset: Int,
                                                              fetchLimit: Int) -> [Event] {

    return CoreStore.fetchAll(From(Event),
                              Where(predicate),
                              OrderBy(descriptors),
                              Tweak { (fetchRequest) -> Void in
                                fetchRequest.fetchOffset = fetchOffset
                                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = fetchLimit
                                fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        }) ?? []
}
```

Comment: Yes. But if you want more help, show some code (and the language you want to do it in).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Swift, but language is not important for me. I'll update my answer with simple code first thing tomorrow.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I'm getting the results (events) in following order: First those with relation to Promotion entity (active or not)  and then all for the City ordered by start  date. However I'd like to make them ordered first by **active** promotion and then by date. I've added transient properties (_active_ - Promotion and _inPromotion_ - Event), however I'm not able to sort on them in fetch request. Also I'm using paging, and I'm not sure what will be the best practice to apply sort on fetched data. To make persistent such property also doesn't seem as an option, because it must be updated every day.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you have to get all `Event` objects, but just in proper order. To do that with such complicated order, that includes relationship, as far as I know you have to fetch all Events and then sort them using `NSArray's` method

```
- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

Here are the pieces of the code

**1. Fetch from Core Data**

```
// get the right context here
NSManagedObjectContext *yourContext;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
// extra line, predicate is nil by default, any other required predicate could be written here
request.predicate = nil;

__block NSArray *results = nil;
[yourContext performBlockAndWait:^{

   NSError *error = nil;
   results = [yourContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

       if (error) {
            // handle error here
        }
    }];
```

Fetch is made manually with core methods and you may use `Magical Record` or any other framework that works with Core Data to make it in a row.

**2. Sort the results**

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSArray *sortedResults = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Event *_Nonnull obj1, Event *_Nonnull obj2) {

    BOOL isObj1InActivePromotion = [weakSelf date:now isBetweenDate:obj1.promotion.start andDate:obj1.promotion.end];
    BOOL isObj2InActivePromotion = [weakSelf date:now isBetweenDate:obj2.promotion.start andDate:obj2.promotion.end];

    // if they eather are in active promotion or no, just compare them by start date of the Event
    if (isObj1InActivePromotion == isObj2InActivePromotion) {
        return [obj1.start compare:obj2.start];
    } else {
        return isObj1InActivePromotion ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```

**3. Additional method to work with NSDate**

This method was used in sorting method

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate *)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate *)beginDate andDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I could't check the code for obvious reasons, so sorry for any typos if they are.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer. I'm already using a third part library (CoreStore), but your code is clear and absolutely readable.  I'm fetching data on batches so after every new batch I'll need to filter it. So probably I should take in different direction and to try different structure for my result (sorted array).

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create "isActive" transection property in Promotion Entity to calculate active record.

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@“start” ascending:YES];
 [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]]; 
 [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

After that you can filter fetch result by sorting :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“isActive == %@", @1];
        NSMutableArray *finalResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

HTH.

Comment: I thought about applying filter on the fetched results. However I'm fetching with limit (pagination) and, if I'm getting this right, I should apply filter to all events I already have not only to the last batch. It may be a little bit slow but I'll give it a try.